# How to make graph on pivot table in axlsx gem

Tags: ruby, pivot-table, axlsx

In axlsx ruby gem making graph on a result of a pivot table is ending in error:

ArgumentError (Missing cell `B228` for the specified range `B228:B233`)

This makes me think that pivot table data is not really created until it is opened in LO or Excel. Is it possible to mitigate the error and put graph data on the sheet?

```rb
  n_row = 223  # row number that program ended preparing data
  # create pivot table. It will have 10 rows
  sheet.add_pivot_table "A#{n_row + 2}:C#{n_row + 10}", "L1:L#{n_row}" do |pivot_table|
    pivot_table.rows    = ['Group']
    pivot_table.data = [ref: 'Group', :subtotal => 'count', num_fmt: 4]
  end
  # create chart
  sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, start_at: "D#{n_row + 2}", end_at: "E#{n_row + 20}") do |chart|
    chart.add_series data: sheet["B#{n_row + 5}:B#{n_row + 10}"],
                     labels: sheet["A#{n_row + 5}:A#{n_row + 10}"],
                     title: "Graph by groups",
                     colors: @products.map { "00FF00" }
  end
```

by
TheR

Comment: Can you please post some code as to how you are going about this?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the pivot table is successful? e.g. the pivot table works if you comment out the chart. Another option might be to use a defined name instead of the cell references

Comment: The document opens with a pivot table in LO without problems.

Excel displays an error in data format when opening the document, but shows the pivot table.